# How to combine a forEach with Promises.all

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I am doing a function which uploads images to AWS from an input file field and then save the image URL and name to mongoDB. I am using NodeJS and MongoDB. Here is my example:

```
uploadFile(req, res, next) {

 let files = req.files;
 let images = [];


  files.file.forEach((file) => {

    uploadToAWS(file.path, {}, function(err, img) {

    if (err) { throw err; }

        // add path and name to images array

        images.push({
          path: img[0].url,
          name: img[0].name,
        });
    });
  });
    // Here the promises should resolve and save to MongoDB the array images
 },
```

Instead of saving to the database each time the loop iterate through the elements I just populate an array `images` and then save it to DB.

Comment: It's not the best idea. If there is an error, you will have orphaned files on S3 without any references in the db.

Answer (score 10):

For this, you want to use [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) rather than [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). That is because you are intending to map some values to promises based on each of those values.

```
return Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
    // do some stuff with each file here
}));
```

A full example would look something like this:

```
uploadFile(req, res, next) {
  let files = req.files;
  let images = [];

  const promises = files.file.map((file) => {
    return uploadToAWS(file.path, {}).then((img) => {
      // add path and name to images array

      images.push({
        path: img[0].url,
        name: img[0].name,
      });
    });
  });

  // Here the promises should resolve and save to MongoDB the array images
  Promise.all(promises).then(next);
}
```

Note that here, I assume `uploadToAws()` is capable of returning a promise, as that is necessary to make this work, otherwise the house of <del>cards</del> promises comes crashing down. If there is no built-in support of promises from `uploadToAws()`, you can use a *promisify* utility like [pify](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pify) to wrap the function with an adapter that will create a promise for you based on the result of the callback.

#### Resources

- http://2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html
- http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bluebird's [`promisify`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) to make your 
`uploadToAWS()` return a promise instead of taking a callback (you can also do it easily without `promisify` but it's useful) because it's much easier to use functions returning promises if you want to use Promise.all etc. If you want to use functions that take callbacks then I recommend using the [Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) module to manage the control flow.

When you promisify your `uploadToAWS()` then you will be able to do something like:

```
let promises = files.file.map(file => uploadToAWS(file.path, {}));
```

Then you'll be able to use:

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((imgs) => {
    // everything succeeded
  }).catch((error) => {
    // there was an error
  });
```

or, if you're using async/await:

```
try {
  let imgs = await Promise.all(promises);
  // everything succeeded
} catch (error) {
  // there was an error
}
```

Now whenever you have `imgs` it's an array of objects returned by `uploadToAWS()` (or, strictly speaking, an array of resolution values of the promises returned by `uploadToAWS()` after all of them are already resolved).

You can use that array to create another array like your `images`:

```
let images = imgs.map(img => ({
  path: img[0].url,
  name: img[0].name,
});
```

or:

```
let images = imgs.map(img => ({
  path: img.url,
  name: img.name,
});
```

depending on what is actually returned by `uploadToAWS()` because you didn't specify that.

But remember that when you have an error you will need to recover from it by removing the uploaded files that are no longer needed.

Comment: The problem using `.map` is if user upload only 1 image then map fails, but if user upload more than one `.map` works fine... the reason is with multiple files it sends an array of objects, but with a single file it just sends just an object.